# R: Share factor levels between different list items?

Tags: r

I am working with a dataframe, where one of the columns is a multivalued variable, which I've implemented as a list as column. 
Here's a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(title=c('one','two','three'), subjects=I(list(c('A'), c('A','B','C','D'), c('B','D','E'))))
```

The general idea being that I can attach as many subjects as I'd like without using too much space.
Now the set of possible subjects isn't that large, so if it were a simple column, I'd turn it into a factor. But if I do that here, R stores the levels attribute separately for each list item, (i.e. each row), once again needing a huge amount of storage.

Does anyone know of a way to store a list of factors, with the levels of these factors as a shared attribute?

The only thing I could think of was to do it myself, store the values as integers and create a separate lookup-table, but that doesn't look very efficient.

Comment: How about storing your data in long format and turning both variables into factor columns? For example `str(data.frame(title = rep(df$title, lengths(df$subjects)), subjects = unlist(df$subjects)))`

Comment: To clarify: you are explicitly *not*  looking for a way to have the same levels copied for every row, but instead you want one "levels" (the shared attribute) that every row refers to.

Comment: @KenS That's exactly right. Mostly because I have quite a large dataset (1.6M rows), and performance, so I don't want the levels to be stored 1.6M times

Comment: @Docendo I could try that as well, but I have more variables than in the example, which means I should either copy those variables as well, or work with different dataframes, more like a RelDB model. Which means more work in that direction. But I'll look into it, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Your idea of storing integers is good. You don't need a "separate lookup-table", but a separate factor: `f <- factor(unique(do.call(c, df$subjects))) ; df$subjects <- lapply(df$subjects, match, levels(f))` then get actual values on an as-needed basis with `levels(f)[df$subjects[[3]]]` for instance. Early comparisons done with `pryr::object_size` look good (though I haven't properly benched memory usage yet). Also, for performance (speed and mem usage as well), the usual recommendation: have a look at `data.table`.